# When does the diagonal cantor argument apply

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know a lot of thing have been written on the cantor diagonal argument. I have understand it pretty well. I mean, I understand how it works. But my problem is: I never know when I should use it and especially when does it apply? So my question is: which assumptions do we need to apply the cantor diagonalization argument?

Thanks

Comment: Basically when you have a sequence $(u_{n,p})$ with nice properties for the sequences $(u_{n,p})$ for a fixed $n$ and $(u_{p,n})$ for a fixed $p$, then you try to consider the sequence $v_n = u_{n,n}$ (diagonal of $u$) in order to get the properties of both sequences.

Comment: Ok but so you don't need the set the sequences live in to be closed?

Comment: No. Though it may help if you live in a complete space...

Answer (score 1):

**The** Cantor's diagonal argument works only to prove that $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$ are not equinumerous, and that $X$ and $\mathcal P(X)$ are not equinumerous for every set $X$.

There are *variants of the same idea* that will help you prove other things, but "the same idea" is a pretty informal measure. The best one can really say is that the idea works when it works, and if you can make it work in a context where one wouldn't have thought it applied, then more power to you!

In particular, it is not as if "diagonal argument" is a mechanical procedure that you can point at every problem in a particular well-defined class, and then "crank the handle" to get results. It is more of a intuitive design principle that it is nice to be conversant with because it is often useful, than a particular tool.

We could phrase the general idea somewhat like:

> Suppose you have sets $A$ and $B$ where $A\subseteq B$, and you want to prove that $A\ne B$. This means you have to produce a $b_0\in B$ that is not in $A$. If the elements of $B$ don't need to have a lot of internal structure, you may be able to get away with stitching your $b_0$ together from little pieces, each piece corresponding to one $a\in A$ in a way such that this piece ensures that $b_0\ne a$.

(The "diagonal" comes about because each $a$ is typically used *twice* in the construction of $b_0$, namely once to determine where in $b_0$ its piece goes, and then once to make sure that this piece differs from the corresponding piece of $a$ itself).

In Cantor's original case we have an arbitrary function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$, and we're applying the argument to $A=f(\mathbb N)$ and $B=\mathbb R$; it produces a $b_0$ that is not in the range of $f$, which proves that $f$ is not surjective.

It is easy to extend this to other cases of proving non-equinumerosity, but that is not all it can do.

For example, we can prove that the halting problem is undecidable. Here we assume that there's a Turing machine $T$ that inputs a pair $(x,y)$ and then purports to tell us whether $T_x$ halts on input $y$. Now we let $B$ be the set of all Turing machines, and $A$ be the set of machines that our $T$ works correctly on. Then we construct $b_0$ as the machine that does

```
read a;
run T on (a,a);
if T answers that T_a halts on a;
  then loop forever
  otherwise halt
```

This ensures that $b_0$ will *behave differently* from $a$ if $T$ gives truthful answers about $a$ -- and therefore $b_0$ cannot be one of the Turing machines that $T$ gives the right answer to; in particular $T$ doesn't work for *every* Turing machine.

This example also shows another commonality with Cantor's original argument, namely that we're trying to prove that something *can't exist*, and the argument goes that if it did exist then we could define an $A$ that actually equalled $B$, but the construction of a $b_0$ would still work, which is absurd.

---

Even further generalizations of "diagonalization" appears in logic, for example in *Gödel's incompleteness theorem*, where a core part of the argument is about somehow "applying a function or process to a description of the process itself". This idea intuitively also seems to be present in the diagonalizations above, but Gödel's usage doesn't appear to be easy to shoehorn into the $A/B$ scheme above. It seems to be reasonable to say that Gödel's diagonalization is not really a variant of *Cantor's* diagonal argument.